# Regexp with sub-strings depending on previous string

Tags: regex

Using regexp, I want to remove a string prefix which starts with a word `foo` and which is *optionally* by another pattern: `:bar`. However, I do NOT want to match any other pattern containing `:`:

- fooHELLO - match and capture foo
- foo:barHELLO - match and capture foo:bar
- foo:xHELLO - NO MATCH

So how do I make the `:` optional, but *if* it's there, it must be followed by `bar`?

I tried this:

```
^foo(:bar)?(?!:)
```

And it almost works, however since there's no relation between the optional accepted string and the optional forbidden string, the last case here doesn't work:

```
fooHELLO -> ✅ HELLO
foo:barHELLO -> ✅ HELLO
foo:XHELLO _> ✅ no match
foo:bar:HELLO -> ❌ no match, but should be :HELLO
```

If I use a logical `or`:

```
^foo((:bar)|(?:[^:]))
```

Then instead the first one fails:

```
fooHELLO -> ELLO ❌ H was consumed
foo:barHELLO -> ✅ HELLO
foo:XHELLO _> ✅ no match
foo:bar:HELLO -> ✅ :HELLO
```

So how can I make a regexp with "either `foo` is followed by `:bar` and then match `foo:bar`, or `foo` is followed by something that does not start with `:` and then match just `foo`", so that it can be used with JavaScript `String.replace(pattern, '')` function to get rid of the prefix?

Comment: Maybe something like `^foo(?!:(?!bar))(?::bar)?`? See https://regex101.com/r/pjgJir/1

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://regex101.com/r/gJ7PiJ/1

Regex: `(?<=foo:bar|foo(?!:)).*$`

Rough human translation: look behind to see foo:bar or foo followed by not a colon and then capture till the end from there

**Note** this captures everything after the foo:bar/foo pattern (so the HELLO part from your examples)